# Using a variable from Oracle AS clause

Tags: oracle

I'm using the following as part of a query

```
SELECT 
    MEMO_COMMENT as MEMO,
    INSTR(MEMO, 'PD') AS PastDue
    FROM table
```

The error I receive is  "MEMO": invalid identifier

I also tried

```
` WITH MEMO AS (select MEMO_COMMENT FROM table) 
 select INSTR(MEMO, 'PD') AS PastDue`
 FROM table
```

and received the same error

Is there a way to declare the field like this?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You don't need `as`. You may assign an alias by just leaving a space. Try doing `Select MEMO_COMMENT MEMO, ....`

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, you can't use the alias as a select field at the same nesting level, so it is the second reference that is wrong:

```
SELECT 
    MEMO_COMMENT as MEMO,
    INSTR(MEMO, 'PD') AS PastDue
    FROM table
```

Should be:

```
SELECT 
    MEMO_COMMENT        as MEMO,
    INSTR(MEMO_COMMENT , 'PD') AS PastDue
    FROM table
```

Or you can reference the alias from a higher nesting level, for example:

```
 SELECT 
        INSTR(MEMO , 'PD') AS PastDue
        FROM  ( SELECT         
                MEMO_COMMENT  as MEMO
                FROM table )
```

For the second, the WITH statement, you are aliasing the dataset as a table named MEMO - not the field. This would work though:

```
WITH MEM_DATA AS (select MEMO_COMMENT as MEMO FROM table) 
 select INSTR(MEMO, 'PD') AS PastDue`
 FROM MEM_DATA;
```

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't fully understand the with clause. Thank you.